# Why couldn't the Carnotaurus speak in the Dinosaur film from Disney?

Tags: disney, dinosaur-2000

All the other dinosaur species could talk, except the Velociraptors and the Carnotaurus. Why couldn't they speak?

Comment: https://sailorgojirarex1997.tumblr.com/post/143702029774/conceptual-artwork-for-the-first-variant-of - To make the film more "commercially viable", the decision was (apparently) made to make the dinosaurs able to speak to each other. It follows that the carnivores can also communicate, just not with the audience (probably)

Comment: Maybe they just choose not to converse with their potential meal. Judging by Arthur Dent's reaction to the Ameglian Major Cow in HHGTTG (and that's an animal that actively _wants_ to be eaten), it can be quite disconcerting to "meet the meat".

Comment: I thought the movie was great, until I heard one of the characters speak.

Answer (score 4):

They couldn't talk for the same reason they were much larger and scarier-looking in the movie than real-life carnotaurs--for drama.

"Eric Leighton, one of the directors, basically admitted . . . that they would "cheat like hell" because they were not creating a documentary." (Tvtropes- 
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Disney/DinoSAUR)

Not allowing predators to speak in talking animal  stories is common.  In The Land Before Time movies, plant-eaters speak but the sharp-tooth can only roar unless in a sequel a cute baby one shows up.

Comment: Can you confirm the original source of that quote. I've seen it several places, but never with attribution; http://dino.wikia.com/wiki/Dinosaur_(film) (for example)